# How do I pick a random object from an array that I fetched from an API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, fetch-api

very new to programming here. I am working on a group project, and I am currently trying to pick a game at random from the Free-to-Play Games Database after filtering by platform. Right now, I simply want to log the result to my console to make sure that the "pick at random" function is working. I have a different function to retrieve the array of games playable in browser, and that looks like this:

```
// gets data for playable games in browser only and logs to console
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'INSERT-KEY-HERE',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'free-to-play-games-database.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
};
fetch('https://free-to-play-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/api/games?platform=browser', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Note, we have an API key, I'm just not including it in the post.

I've tried to start writing a function that is modeled after a fellow group member's for a drink-related API, and right now mine looks like this:

```
//pulls random game
function gameApi(selection){
    console.log(selection);
    var apiURL=('free-to-play-games-database.p.rapidapi.com'+ selection)
    console.log(apiURL);
    fetch(apiURL).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }) .then(function(data) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.response.length);
        var randomGame = (data.response[random].strGame);
        console.log(randomGame);
        var gameUrl = ('https://free-to-play-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/api/games?    platform=browser'+randomGame);
        console.log(gameUrl);
        fetch(gameUrl).then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function (data){
            console.log(data);
        })
    });

}
```

When I run the function in my console, it says that it failed to fetch the data and does not return a game from the array. Since I'm new to programming, I only have a very rough idea what I'm doing, so I'm not entirely sure which part is going wrong.

EDIT: I am no longer getting the error that it failed to fetch the data after putting "options" into the first fetch of the second codeblock. Now I am getting an error that it "cannot read properties of undefined" regarding the length of the array, which I think is necessary to pick at random.

Comment: seems like the error is "simple", `it says that it failed to fetch the data `. so the issue is in the connection or the authentication.

try using firefox with it's devtools. it will show you what was sent and received

Comment: In your code (second codeblock) you call the API using `fetch(apiURL/gameUrl)` (without options), so you're not sending the essential headers that are send in the first codeblock.

Comment: @3limin4t0r How would I include the headers?

Comment: If the `options` variable is still in scope you can just pass it as the second parameter, the same way you're passing it in the first codeblock. `fetch(apiURL, options)` If the variable is no longer in scope you could pass the headers directly `fetch(apiURL, { headers: { ... } })`

Comment: Update: I have gotten it to fetch the data I believe, because that error is gone. However, it now says "cannot read properties of undefined" when referring to data.response.length. I think this might be why it is unable to return a random object, because it can't read how long the array is. But in the first codeblock it displays that information just fine, so how can I fix this new error?

Comment: That's because you need to `return` the result of your fetches.